# 64gb USB Drive data suddenly lost after OS upgrade - showing "EFI" and 200mb capacity and no data

Tags: data-recovery

I left my USB drive plugged in during a Windows OS upgrade.

I backed up all my data on this drive, and now in the new OS (Windows Server 2016) it is showing no data (.Trashes folder only) and 200mb capacity.

Obviously my data is still there, but somehow the partitions messed up?

Can I recover this or am I out of luck without any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this and recover all my data.

In Disk Management I discovered there were two partitions.  One EFI (protected), and one primary (with all my data).

I learned for some reason Windows only accesses the first partition on removable media.

So I used `DISKPART` to delete the first partition.

Example:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 2
list partition
select partition 1
delete partition override
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer since? That EFI system partition is where the boot files are stored. I'm not sure why they would be on an external drive. Hopefully the correct boot files and configuration exist on the main drive still.

Comment: Yep!  Everything booting normally.  I have no idea why an EFI partition got installed on it.  I sadly do not know if it already existed on it or if the Windows Server put it on during the upgrade.